# Swift: NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable - Dynamic buffer

Tags: swift, buffer, tcpclient, nsstream

I download a text file from a server using the following Swift code on an iOS application:

```
func stream(theStream : NSStream, handleEvent streamEvent : NSStreamEvent)
    {
        println("stream event \(streamEvent)")

        switch (streamEvent)
        {
            case NSStreamEvent.None:
                println("NSStreamEventNone")

            case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
                println("NSStreamEventOpenCompleted")

            case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
                println("NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable")
                if let inputStream = theStream as? NSInputStream
                {
                    //println("is NSInputStream")
                    if inputStream.hasBytesAvailable
                    {
                        //println("hasBytesAvailable")
                        let bufferSize = 4096
                        var buffer = Array<UInt8>(count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)

                        var bytesRead: Int = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)

                        // If read bytes are less than 0 -> error
                        if bytesRead < 0
                        {
                            self.error = self.inputStream!.streamError
                            closeNetworkCommunication()
                        }

                        // If read bytes equal 0 -> close connection
                        else if bytesRead == 0
                        {
                            closeNetworkCommunication()
                        }

                        // If read bytes are greater than 0
                        else if bytesRead > 0
                        {
                            var messageFromServer: NSString = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                            //println(output)

                            messageReceived(messageFromServer)

                            closeNetworkCommunication()
                        }
                    }
                }

            case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
                println("NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable")

            case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
                println("NSStreamEventErrorOccurred")

            case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
                println("NSStreamEventEndEncountered")

            default:
                println("Unknown event")
        }
    }
```

The file is downloaded just fine, except it is limited to the buffer size (4096) and therefore is often truncated. There are a lot of files that could be downloaded, the size ranging from 1 kb to 300 kb and potentially more. So, I can make the buffer size equal 4096000, for example, and it will download the whole file. But is there a better way to set an unlimited (i.e. dynamic) buffer?

EDIT:

I modified the code to the following:

```
case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
      var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
                if ( theStream == self.inputStream)
                {

                    while (self.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable)
                    {
                        var len = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)

                        // If read bytes are less than 0 -> error
                        if len < 0
                        {
                            self.error = self.inputStream!.streamError
                            println("Input stream has less than 0 bytes")
                            closeNetworkCommunication()
                        }

                        // If read bytes equal 0 -> close connection
                        else if len == 0
                        {
                            println("Input stream has 0 bytes")
                            closeNetworkCommunication()
                        }


                        if(len > 0)
                        {
                            var messageFromServer = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                            messageReceived(messageFromServer!)
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

It works now and downloads the complete file. The question I have now is whether I need to close the TCP connection after the file has been downloaded and how.

I use the following to close communication:

```
func closeNetworkCommunication()
    {

        self.inputStream?.close()
        self.outputStream?.close()

        self.inputStream?.removeFromRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        self.outputStream?.removeFromRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        self.inputStream?.delegate = nil
        self.outputStream?.delegate = nil

        self.inputStream = nil;
        self.outputStream = nil;

        //self.inputBuffer = nil;
        self.outputBuffer = nil;

        println("LOAD CLOSENETWORKCOMMUNICATION")
    }
```

So if I close the network in the HasBytesAvailable clause, it stops loading the message and crashes (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value). Even if I close the network in my messageReceived(messageFromServer!) method at the end, the same thing happens. How do I close the network without truncating the file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: hasBytesAvailable may happen *more than once*. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html